# Вопрос по построению фразы

Tags: стилистика

*Под ногой шуршат*

*Как деревьев письма.*

Можно так сказать?

Answer (score 4):

Фраза задумана красивой, но предложение кажется недостроенным.

Сравнительный оборот "*как деревьев письма*" должен быть привязан по смыслу к какому-то существительному, *письма* должны быть сравнимы с другим *шуршащим* предметом, например: *Под ногой шуршат листья, как деревьев письма.*

Comment: Вот эти стихи (надеюсь, автор не против): В позолоте сад, 
Облетают листья, 
Под ногой шуршат 
Как деревьев письма.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Цитата очень кстати.

Comment: Милые стихи Веры Киреевой.

Comment: За окном дождит 
И холодный ветер 
В проводах гудит 
Об ушедшем лете. 

В позолоте сад, 
Облетают листья, 
Под ногой шуршат 
Как деревьев письма.  

Одинокий клён
Задремал в печали. 
Ему снился сон,
Где дожди молчали. 

Там цветут сады,  
Зеленеют травы, 
И поют дрозды  
В зарослях дубравы. 

А сейчас дожди
И душа в миноре,
Холода в пути,
Снегопадов море.

27.09.2016

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, автор не случайно обошёлся *без запятой* перед "как" - чтобы последующее не трактовалось как формальное *сравнение* с **неведомой** сущностью "*письма деревьев*": (как уже заметила Екатерина) это не может *пояснять*, как именно шуршат листья. Скорее, было желание передать своё ощущение от звука шуршащих листьев (начало предложения - о них): казалось, что деревья шлют какие-то загадочные послания в виде шуршащих писем. Выбранное для рифмы и поддержания ритма "как" без запятой можно формально трактовать как "статус" упомянутых перед этим листьев (аналог выражения "/этакими/ письмами, которые, казалось, слали деревья" сентиментальному автору, т. е. "в качестве") - думаю, такая *поэтическая вольность* допускается законами жанра.

Answer (score 2):

(1) В позолоте сад, (2)**Облетают** листья, Под ногой **шуршат**, как деревьев письма.

Это БСП, а во втором предложении **однородные сказуемые** (листья облетают,  шуршат). Здесь инверсия обстоятельства "под ногой", поэтому грамматика не сразу кажется ясной.

Comment: Мне стихи нравятся, поэтому попытаюсь их защитить. Что если считать, что "как деревьев письма" относится ко всему сразу (т.е.  облетающие и шуршащие листья  - как деревьев письма)? Можно написать: "В позолоте сад; облетают листья, под ногой шуршат - как деревьев письма"?

Comment: А вообще-то, Вы, кажется, правы, поэтому я исправляю ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Это же стихи. Лирика. Автор вправе создавать личные метафоры и сравнения.
Только перед "как" запятая. Но если задуматься, то не совсем ясно, с чего бы письмам шуршать. Можно поразмыслить, что могут "делать" письма. Либо смысл поменять - не *шуршат* в данном случае, а *лежат*, например. Прощальные такие письма. Непрочитанные. Довольно печально, когда над стихами возникает задача поработать - вместить что-либо в ритм и подстроить под размер, стопу...

- Апдейт. Я дала маху: шуршащие письма - довольно распространённое
  сочетание. Приношу извинения.

Answer (score 0):

В позолоте сад,

Облетают листья,

Под ногой шуршат

Как деревьев письма.

Мне нравится - и построение фразы, и всё сравнение,и метафора "деревьев письма". По крайней мере  грамматической ошибки нет точно. И значение "шуршат письмами" тоже возможно, значит, и запятая **не**обязательна.